# Through Associations in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some issues with through associations in rails 3. I'm getting a 'undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass' error.

**View**

```
<% @comparison.each do |v| %>
<%= link_to v.trial.user.full_name, trial_trials_path %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def search
   @comparison = Result.where('variety_id' => [params[:variety_one], params[:variety_two]], 'year' => params[:year]).
   joins(:trial).where('trials.irrigated' => params[:irrigated], 'trials.region_id' => params[:regions])
  end
```

**Result**

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :trial, :primary_key => 'trial_id'
  has_many :users, :through => :trial

end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :trials

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

end
```

**Trial**

```
class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :results
  belongs_to :user, :primary_key => 'user_id'

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `v.trial.user.full_name` - if the Trail has no user, it will try to call full name on a nil object and this will cause the error you are seeing.

Try doing some debugging to find out why the object is nil.

Comment: Cheers Kieran. You're right, some of the entries are empty, but when I do 'unless v.trial.user.full_name.blank?' I get the same error.

Comment: You need to do unless v.trial.user